# How to change default separator icon in Bootstrap 3 Breadcrumbs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way that i can change the default separator ("/") with a custom icon in Bootstrap 3 breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is not icon, you can add what ever you want, icon, image etc.

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    color: #ccc;
    content: "/ ";
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Change content to " >> " and see

Comment: Thanks Gorostas!  So if i want to add custom icon, i just need to add <img> block like this: "...:before { <img goes here...> } ". Am i right?

Comment: No i content: " <----- Here add what you need --- >"

Comment: Or if you're using LESS, change the value of the `@breadcrumb-separator` variable.

Comment: Suppose I want to add an icon, say "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>". How can this be done? If above technique is applied, it displays the raw HTML

Answer (score 9):

And now with bootstrap 4

```css
    .breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before {
       content: "* "; 
       color: green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5

```
<nav style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';" aria-label="breadcrumb">
```

Reference links:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/breadcrumb/